# Unable to save a domain class instance from Groovy Console in GGTS

Tags: grails

I am creating a Grails project using Groovy/Grails Tool Suite. If I choose **Run As >> Groovy Console**, I can create sample objects from my domain classes but cannot save them.

So,

```
new things.Thing(height: 20, length: 30)
```

creates a new Thing, but

```
new things.Thing(height: 20, length: 30).save()
```

throws an exception

```
No signature of method: thing.Thing.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

even though respondsTo states that Things respond to save().

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the Groovy console, not the Grails console. They use the same code and look the same, but the Grails version hooks into the application, whereas the Groovy console just has access to the code. To run the console, go to Grails Tools | Open Grails Command Prompt and enter `console` in the text field.

This is just a GUI wrapper for running `grails console` from the commandline.

Comment: I have a slight problem with that approach also. There is a timeout associated with Grails Launch that shuts down the Grails Console after some amount of inactivity, 60 seconds by default. I would like to keep the console open perpetually, but I am a bit concerned that some other part of GGTS really needs to have this timeout set more tightly, or there will be a risk of freezing up the IDE.

Comment: Are you using Run As | Grails Command? That creates a launch, but if there's a timeout it's pretty useless. If you use the command prompt there's no timeout. Another option is to run `grails console` from a shell.

Comment: I was using Navigate | Open Grails Command Prompt, but the timeout seems to be gone today. It shut down the console three times Friday, but everything seems fine today.